# selectCallback in Shopify.SelectOptions is always returning `null`

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

`selectCallback` sets `variant` equal to `null` on all my option selections besides the initial call. On the initial call, it logs the variant with the first color and size.

```js
const productJson = JSON.parse($(`#${id}`).attr('data-product'));

new Shopify.OptionSelectors(id, {
    product: productJson,
    onVariantSelected: selectCallback,
});

const selectCallback = (variant, select, options) => {
    console.log(variant) // `null`
}
```

I'm expecting to get `variant` object which matches my size/color selections.

Comment: What kind of theme resource is this being invoked from? If you are adding this as a script to an existing theme then the theme may also be calling OptionSelectors with its own selectCallback.  Also is `id` in your constructor a string or a variable?

Answer (score 0):

before you call callback your method should be defind

```
  element.addEventListener('blur', callback, { once: true });

    function callback() {
      element.classList.remove(focusClass);
      element.removeAttribute('tabindex');
    }
```